# Confusion with entity frameworks and ASP.NET forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have a Forms project  that uses ASP.NET membership authentication to manage the users. I also have created model classes that use entity frameworks to populate a database. Currently, I have been planning on keeping the asp tables (membership and other records) in the same database as the tables containing the other application data.

When I run my program after changing some of the data model classes, entity frameworks recreates the entire database, and I've lost all my ASP.net tables.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: IMO, using ASP.NET membership authentication is like delegating your "product" tables to a third-party implementation when in fact it clearly belongs as a first-party citizen of your database schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing, your code it is hard to say. Here is my wild guess.

You might have **[DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679604%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)**. Basically, it drops the entire database when Code First classes change.

If so, you might want to replace it with **[NullDatabaseInitializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn221749(v=vs.113).aspx)** which prevents the schema from being altered.